# Characterization of functions whose epigraph has a self-concordant barrier

Tags: convex-optimization

[Self-concordant barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-concordant_function#barrier), particularly those that can be computed efficiently, are essential ingredients in solving convex optimization problems using interior-point methods. I am particularly interested in barriers to epigraphs of convex functions.

Formally, for any function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}$, define $G_f := \{ (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2: f(x) \leq t, x\geq 0\} = $ the epigraph of $f$.
Let us say that a convex function $f$ is "barrierable" if $G_f$ has a self-concordant barrier that can be computed using a constant number of function evaluations.
*What are the barrierable functions?*

In his [2004 lecture-notes](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/Lect_IPM.pdf), Nemirovsky provides a sufficient condition: Proposition 9.2.2 implies that if $f$ is three-times continuously differentiable on the ray $x>0$, and $x\cdot |f'''(x)|/|f''(x)|$ is bounded by a constant for all $x>0$, then $f$ is barrierable.
However, there is no proof that this condition is necessary.

Questions (from hard to easy):

1. Is there a characterization (a necessary and sufficient condition) of barrierable functions?
2. Are there convex functions that are *provably* not barrierable? Or functions $f$ such that $G_f$ has no efficiently-computable self-concordant barrier unless $P=NP$?
3. Are there some substantially more general sufficient conditions for barrierable functions?